# MongoDB $pull not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am building a Meteor app and I have Contests/Entries collections. When someone enters the contest, their user_id is pushed into the Contest.entered_users array with $addToSet. Here is the code:

```
entryInsert: function(entryAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(entryAttributes, {
        contest_id: String
    });

    var user = Meteor.user();
    var entry = _.extend(entryAttributes, {
        user_id: user._id,
        user_name: user.profile.name,
        submitted: new Date(),
        submitted_day: moment().format('MMM D')
    });

    var currentContest = Contests.findOne(entryAttributes.contest_id);

    // Check to make sure that the person has not already entered the giveaway
    if (currentContest.entered_users.indexOf(entry.user_id) !== -1) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('invalid', "You have already entered the giveaway");
    } else {
        Contests.update(
            currentContest._id,
            {
                $addToSet: {entered_users: entry.user_id},
                $inc: {entries: 1}}
        );
    }


    // Create entry in order to get the entry id
    var entryId = Entries.insert(entry, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err.reason);
        }
    });



    return {
        _id: entryId
    }
}
```

I want to remove a persons user_id from the Contest.entered_users array when an entry is removed. I am trying to use $pull but it doesn't appear to be working... When I remove an entry, the entry.user_id is still in the contest.entered_users array. Here is the relevant code:

```
'click .entry-delete': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentEntry = this;
    var currentEntryId = this._id;

    var contestId = Contests.findOne(currentEntry.contest_id);

    // Update the contest by removing the entry's useer_id from entered_users
    Meteor.call('contestRemoveEntry', contestId, currentEntry, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            alert(error.reason);
        }
    });

    Meteor.call('entryRemove', currentEntryId, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            alert(error.reason);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the contestRemoveEntry method:

```
contestRemoveEntry: function(contestId, currentEntry) {
    Contests.update({ _id: contestId }, { $pull: { entered_users: currentEntry.user_id } } );
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is not working? I've tried other SO solutions but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Is _id of the same type as contestId? If _id type is ObjectID then contestId needs also to be of that type so the query matches. Also, make sure the currentEntry.user_id property value has the same type of the entered_users elements

Comment: if contestId is string and needs to match _id being an ObjectId use: { _id: ObjectId(contestId) }

Comment: I just tried using {_id: ObjectId(contestId) } and got this error "ObjectId is not defined". Any idea why?

Comment: make sure you declare the ObjectId object before using it : var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

Comment: I just tried ```Contests.update(contestId, { $pull: { entered_users: currentEntry.user_id } } ); ``` and it appears to be working... I could have sworn I tried that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is the correct way to make $pull work:

```
Contests.update(contestId, { $pull: { entered_users: currentEntry.user_id } } );
```